# Scale sets for azure marketplace vms

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-resource-manager

Is there a way to create scale sets using azure marketplace vms. I am trying to create a marketplace vm firewall vm to a scale set but there seems to be no option available for that? Has anyone done something similar before? Also i cant generalize that vm since its vendor specific.

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean create VMSS with your VM's VHD?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on which Marketplace item your are looking at. Some of them are backed by an image provided by the Marketplace partner, while others are more complex. You can use any of the images provided in the Marketplace in a scale set, but not the more complex marketplace items. For instance, Sophos and Barracuda  both publish firewall images (publisher/offer/sku/version lists below, taken from here: http://armtg.azurewebsites.net/vm_image_list.html). You can deploy any of these to a scale set by using the proper imageReference in the scale set config (e.g. `{"imageReference": {"sku": "byol", "publisher": "barracudanetworks", "version": "latest", "offer": "barracuda-ng-firewall"}}`)

```
sophos
  sophos-xg
    byol
      1.2.0
      16.1.1
      16.5.2
    payg
      16.1.1
      16.5.2

barracudanetworks
  barracuda-email-security-gateway
    byol
      7.1.100401
      7.1.100402
    hourly
      7.1.100401
      7.1.100402
  barracuda-ng-cc
    byol
      6.2.105700
      7.0.067200
      7.0.109001
      7.0.109002
      7.0.209401
      7.1.037101
  barracuda-ng-firewall
    byol
      6.2.105700
      7.0.067200
      7.0.067201
      7.0.109001
      7.0.109002
      7.0.209401
      7.1.037101
    hourly
      6.2.105700
      7.0.067200
      7.0.067201
      7.0.109001
      7.0.109002
      7.0.209401
      7.1.037101
  waf
    byol
      8.0.101100
      8.0.101101
      8.0.101103
      8.0.101104
      8.0.101401
      8.1.101401
      8.1.101403
      8.1.101901
      9.0.100602
    hourly
      8.0.101100
      8.0.101101
      8.0.101103
      8.0.101104
      8.0.101401
      8.1.101401
      8.1.101403
      8.1.101901
      9.0.100602
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: This is great Thanks. Also is there a way to find the ImageURI for the marketplace images since there is a parameter for that in the Scale Set template?

Comment: Can you share a link to the template? Usually ImageURI refers to a custom image and is specified instead of a Marketplace image. Here's an example of a template to deploy a Marketplace image: https://github.com/gatneil/mvss/blob/minimum-viable-scale-set/azuredeploy.json; and here's one for custom image: https://github.com/gatneil/mvss/blob/custom-image/azuredeploy.json

Comment: Here is the link to the template but i am trying to create a VM in a scale set configuration which has multiple nics, is that possible in Scale Sets? https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/201-vmss-windows-customimage

Comment: i am trying to create a scale set for Palo Alto firewall VM. i have added the image reference as required but its deployment is failing with an error :"code": "DiskProcessingError", "message": "One or more errors occurred while preparing VM disks. See disk instance view for details." Have you seen this before? Thanks

Comment: multi-nic per VM in a scale set is in public preview; for more info, see this github page: https://github.com/gbowerman/azure-myriad/tree/master/preview/network

As for the "DiskProcessingError", to see the instance view you can look in resources.azure.com. It will present a tree of all your resources. If you navigate to the scale set, you should see an option of "instanceView" that might contain more debugging info

Comment: Multi-NIC per VM is now GA.https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/new-networking-features-in-azure-scale-sets/

BTW here's a link to a quickstart template which deploys a Marketplace image: https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/201-vmss-datascience (doesn't have multi-NIC though).